# Is it possible to use LIKE and IN for a WHERE statment?

Tags: sql

I have a list of place names and would like to match them to records in a sql database the problem is the properties have reference numbers after there name. eg. 'Ballymena P-4sdf5g'
Is it possible to use IN and LIKE to match records

```
WHERE dbo.[Places].[Name] IN LIKE('Ballymena%','Banger%')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a common misconception that for the construct

```
b IN (x, y, z)
```

that `(x, y, z)` represents a set. It does not.

Rather, it is merely syntactic sugar for

```
(b = x OR b = y OR b = z)
```

SQL has but one data structure: the table. If you want to query search text values as a set then put them into a table. Then you can `JOIN` your search text table to your `Places` table using `LIKE` in the `JOIN` condition e.g.

```
WITH Places (Name)
     AS
     (
      SELECT Name
        FROM (
              VALUES ('Ballymeade Country Club'), 
                     ('Ballymena Candles'), 
                     ('Bangers & Mash Cafe'), 
                     ('Bangebis')
             ) AS Places (Name)
     ), 
     SearchText (search_text)
     AS
     (
      SELECT search_text
        FROM (
              VALUES ('Ballymena'), 
                     ('Banger')
             ) AS SearchText (search_text)
     )
SELECT * 
  FROM Places AS P1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN SearchText AS S1
          ON P1.Name LIKE S1.search_text + '%';
```

Answer (score 12):

No, but you can use OR instead:

```
WHERE (dbo.[Places].[Name] LIKE 'Ballymena%' OR
       dbo.[Places].[Name] LIKE 'Banger%')
```

Answer (score 2):

well a simple solution would be using regular expression not sure how it's done in sql but probably something similiar to this

```
WHERE dbo.[Places].[Name]  SIMILAR TO '(Banger|Ballymena)';
```

or

```
WHERE dbo.[Places].[Name] REGEXP_LIKE(dbo.[Places].[Name],'(Banger|Ballymena)');
```

one of them should atleast work

Comment: `similar to` is supposedly getting replaced with `regexp_like` in the standard.  We'll see.

Answer (score 1):

you could use OR

```
WHERE 
  dbo.[Places].[Name] LIKE 'Ballymena%' 
  OR dbo.[Places].[Name] LIKE 'Banger%'
```

or split the string at the space, if the places.name is *always* in the same format.

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(dbo.[Places].[Name], 1, CHARINDEX(dbo.[Places].[Name], ' ')) 
  IN ('Ballymena', 'Banger')
```

This might decrease performance, because the database *may* be able to use indexes with like (if the wildcard is at the end you have even a better chance) but most probably not when using substring.

Comment: Unfortunately some place names have spaces in but none the less a good solution +1