# SQL query with NOT LIKE IN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Please help me to write an SQL query with the condition as `NOT LIKE IN`.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE EmpPU NOT Like IN ('%CSE%', '%ECE%', '%EEE%');
```

The above example returns an error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use LIKE and IN for a WHERE statment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335359/is-it-possible-to-use-like-and-in-for-a-where-statment)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You cannot combine `LIKE` and `IN`.

The statement below would do the job though:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 
WHERE EmpPU NOT LIKE '%CSE%' 
  AND EmpPU NOT LIKE '%ECE%' 
  AND EmpPU NOT LIKE '%EEE%';
```

Answer (score 27):

That's because you're mixing two syntax together.

If you always have exactly those three values, you can just AND the results of three LIKE expressions.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Table1
WHERE
      EmpPU NOT LIKE '%CSE%'
  AND EmpPU NOT LIKE '%ECE%'
  AND EmpPU NOT LIKE '%EEE%'
```

If you need to do it for "any number" of values, you can put the values into a table and do a join.

```
WITH
  myData
AS
(
            SELECT '%CSE%' AS match
  UNION ALL SELECT '%ECE%' AS match
  UNION ALL SELECT '%EEE%' AS match
)

SELECT
  *
FROM
  Table1
LEFT JOIN
  myData
    ON Table1.EmpPU LIKE myData.match
WHERE
  myData.match IS NULL
```

OR...

```
WITH
  myData
AS
(
            SELECT '%CSE%' AS match
  UNION ALL SELECT '%ECE%' AS match
  UNION ALL SELECT '%EEE%' AS match
)

SELECT
  *
FROM
  Table1
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM myData WHERE Table1.EmpPU LIKE match)
```

Answer (score 21):

If you have set of words which you want to include/exclude in search from a particular column. You may want to use regular expression function of mysql.

**Exclude set of words from a column :**

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Table1
WHERE
      EmpPU NOT REGEXP 'CSE|ECE|EEE';
```

**Search set of words from a column :**

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Table1
WHERE
      EmpPU REGEXP 'CSE|ECE|EEE';
```

Comment: This is a better answer since it is more along the lines of `NOT LIKE IN (...)`, making it easier to maintain the query.  Performance-wise the regex might be more difficult.

Comment: The OP is asking about T-SQL.

Answer (score 6):

you cant combine LIKE and IN

you can do:

```
select * from Table1
where EmpPU not in ('%CSE%', '%ECE%', '%EEE%')
```

but you wont benefit from the % wildcard

if you need the % the only option is:

```
Select * from Table1
where EmpPU not like '%CSE%' and  EmpPU not like '%ECE%' and EmpPU not like '%EEE%'
```

Comment: Except that you mean `AND` rather than `OR`?  And you need to specify the field name in there too?  *[The last part of this answer is character for character identical to a deleted answer...]*

Comment: no, its OR. Only one of the conditions must be true to exclude the record. A row with "EEE" in it must be excluded, but it is not like CSE

Comment: That is exactly the point.  A row is ***included*** if the WHERE clause evaluates to true, to let's take `'SMEEEG'` as an example and try your code...  `('SMEEEG' NOT LIKE '%CSE%') OR ('SMEEEG' NOT LIKE '%ECE%') OR ('SMEEEG' NOT LIKE '%EEE%')` => `(TRUE) OR (TRUE) OR (FALSE)` => `TRUE`.  Your code includes `'SMEEEG'` even though it ***is*** like `'%EEE%'`.  You need `NOT((x LIKE a) OR (x LIKE b) OR (x LIKE c))` or you need `(x NOT LIKE a) AND (x NOT LIKE b) AND (x NOT LIKE c)`.  Either way, what you have doesn't work.  Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can do it like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
        (
            SELECT '%CSE%' AS column1 UNION ALL 
            SELECT '%ECE%' UNION ALL 
            SELECT '%EEE%'
        ) AS tbl
        WHERE Table1.EmpPU LIKE tbl.column1
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
Select * from Table1 where 
    EmpPU NOT Like '%CSE%'  
AND EmpPU NOT Like '%ECE%' 
AND EmpPU NOT Like '%EEE%'
```

Comment: I want in a one go of all parameters instead of write multiple `NOT LIKE` words

Comment: With your query getting `ERROR` as `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Like'.`

Answer (score 0):

Code is as below:

```
Select * from Table1 where 
        (EmpPU NOT Like '%CSE%'  
    OR EmpPU NOT Like '%ECE%' 
    OR EmpPU NOT Like '%EEE%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use `EXCEPT`:

```
    SELECT * FROM Table1 
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM Table1 
    WHERE EmpPU LIKE '%CSE%'  
       OR EmpPU LIKE '%ECE%' 
       OR EmpPU LIKE '%EEE%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server's STRING_SPLIT and use a mix of wildcards.

```
DECLARE @IgnoreWords NVARCHAR(MAX)= '%Word1%,%Word2,Word3%,Word4';

SELECT MyTable.MyCol
FROM
(SELECT 'xxWord1xx' AS MyCol) AS MyTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT value AS ToIgnore FROM STRING_SPLIT(@IgnoreWords, ',')) AS Words
    WHERE MyTable.MyCol LIKE Words.ToIgnore)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to others examples but uses a CTE and a SQL Server table value constructor. References:

- TVC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
- CTE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

This is similar to using `UNION` or the `STRING_SPLIT` examples but I find this syntax slightly cleaner when I am changing the match conditions list and the list gets quite long. You could also join your `unlike` `v` CTE to some other table for a more complex scenario.

```
;WITH unlike AS 
(
    SELECT v.notme
    FROM (VALUES
        ('%CSE%'),
        ('%ECE%'),
        ('%EEE%')
        ) AS v (notme) 
)
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM unlike WHERE t.EmpPU LIKE unlike.notme)
```