# Display all results unless a particular phrase exists in one column

Tags: sql

In order to archive a database row I am inserting the phrase "Yes" into a column `arcFault`.

```
UPDATE fault SET faultArc=@faultArc WHERE faultID = {0}
```

This means when the row has a "Yes" it is not to be displayed on the `SELECT *` statement.

I have tried (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393439/sql-query-with-not-like-in) SO article here):

```
SELECT * FROM fault WHERE faultArc NOT Like '%Yes%'
```

The above does work, but it hides all rows even without "Yes" in column `faultArc`.

How can I get round this? Display all data, except any data with a "Yes" in the `faultArc` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like will filter out the nulls. You can include nulls result by adding condition in `OR`:

```
select *
from fault
where faultArc not like '%Yes%'
    or faultArc is null;
```