# SQL: trying to avoid names with certain elements

Tags: sql, character, wildcard

Basically I'm trying to find products who's names don't have a (GS) or (TD) in them. I tried implementing this:

```
AND c.name NOT IN ('%(TD)%', '%(GS)%')
```

But that didn't filter out names containing those elements, so now I'm left to write this nasty code:

```
AND c.name NOT LIKE '%(TD)%'
AND c.name NOT LIKE '%(GS)%'
```

I know this is a beyond basic question and it has probably been asked somewhere here, maybe I'm not phrasing it correctly when searching. Would love to find a way to write this much more efficiently, it's driving me nuts.

EDIT: Even though the second method is correct, I don't understand how the following code would work:

```
c.name IN ('%Jordan%', '%adidas%').
```

By that logic, why couldn't my original method work? The whole point of the IN operator was to make this convenient after all.

Comment: You don't like the second version because it's two lines? It is the most legible way to write this I'd think.

Comment: Your "nasty code" is how this logic is written in SQL

Comment: Your two line statement looks correct to me also, but I see some other options on this thread:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393439/sql-query-with-not-like-in

Comment: Agreedo: you're doing it right, but it is annoyingly verbose.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? `ALL` or `ANY` might be a possible shortcut in some.

Answer (score 0):

Your last edit wouldn't work. The `IN` operator determines whether a specified value matches any value in a sub-query or list, returning `Boolean`. This is the same way of using `OR` with `=`. That is,

```
select column from table where column in ('a', 'b')
```

Is the same as

```
select column from table where column = 'a' or column = 'b'
```

`LIKE` allows you to use wildcards and some watered down regex like expressions. But you can't mix these. For example, your edited query would not return any results for Jordan or Adidas.

```
declare @table table (name varchar(64))
insert into @table
values
('Jordan'),
('adidas'),
('Jordans'),
('adidass')

select *
from @table
where name in ('%Jordan%','%adidas%')
```

This is because this query is computed as

```
select * from @table where name = '%Jordan%' or name = '%adidas%'
```

Notice `%` is treated as part of the string literal here, and not a wild card operator.

Comment: Ok so, then my original method is the only way to do this? I didn't know if there was a more efficient way to achieve this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Correct, using `OR` is how, and the only want to achieve this logic.