# Calling Search Parameters in SQL for multiple SQL Scripts.

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to create a variable like call to be used holding the search parameters for a SQL "Select" call?. I have multiple SELECT SQL queries that use the same parameters for EXCLUDING certain data. That would be in the "NOTLIKE" portion of the code.

Can you have one variable in the SQL code that can be called in multiple SQL scripts is my question.

This will be for MS SQL Server Management Studio v17.8.1 and MS SQL Server 2008.

```
SELECT distinct DB.[ReportNumber]
      ,DB.[StatusText]
      ,DB.[ProjActStageName]
      ,DB.[ProjectOwnerTypeName]
      ,DB.[ProjTypeName]
      ,DB.[ProjWorkTypeName]

FROM [Database]
WHERE DB.ReportNumber = DP.ReportNumber

AND DB.ProjTypeName IN ('Custom House', 'Spec Houses')
AND DB.ProjectName NOT LIKE '%Repair%'
AND DB.ProjectName NOT LIKE '%Replace%'
AND DB.ProjectName NOT LIKE '%Abatement%'
ORDER BY DB.ReportNumber
```

TO -->

```
 SELECT distinct DB.[ReportNumber]
          ,DB.[StatusText]
          ,DB.[ProjActStageName]
          ,DB.[ProjectOwnerTypeName]
          ,DB.[ProjTypeName]
          ,DB.[ProjWorkTypeName]

    FROM [Database]
    WHERE DB.ReportNumber = DP.ReportNumber

    AND DB.ProjTypeName IN ('Custom House', 'Spec Houses')
   (Variable excluding certain data) 
   ORDER BY DB.ReportNumber"
```

Comment: The only ways i can think of involve dynamic sql and a splitter function. Seems like more work

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read this thread for some options on how to approach your problem: [SQL Query with NOT LIKE IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393439/sql-query-with-not-like-in)