# how do you use like not expression more than once in one column in sql neat and simple?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
select  (Col_Name) 
where (Col_Name) not like '%abc%'
and (Col_Name) not like '%cap%'
and (Col_Name) not like '%tis%'
and (Col_Name) not like '%sat%'
and (col_Name) not like '%plk%'
```

Comment: There is no other way than what you're doing, although what you're doing there without a `FROM tablename` and with parentheses around the column names is an error.

Comment: Which RDBMS (SQLServer, Oracle, MySQL etc) is this? I would expect this to be possible using regular expressions, but not all versions of SQL support regular expressions.

Comment: Please add smaple data and result that you are try to achive? or you can use regular expression

Comment: @MarkBannister I use SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use LIKE and IN for a WHERE statment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335359/is-it-possible-to-use-like-and-in-for-a-where-statment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server does not support regular expressions natively though you can install a CLR function to use them.

One way of achieving this would be

```
SELECT *
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  col_Name IS NOT NULL AND
           NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                       FROM   (VALUES ('abc'),
                                      ('cap'),
                                      ('tis'),
                                      ('sat'),
                                      ('plk')) V(C)
                       WHERE  col_Name LIKE '%' + C + '%')
```

Though I don't see that as an improvement.

Comment: +1 Nice answer, although I agree it isn't really any more readable or easier to maintain.

Comment: Also if `col_Name` is nullable this still needs two references to `col_Name` to maintain the original semantics.

Comment: Love the idea. Thank you Martin Smith.