# Determine primary key by non-primary contents of row in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, string, search, primary-key

So I have a table. This table contains information for the profile of a user on my site. The primary key for the tab;e is a user ID. If I wanted to get the user's profile information, I could do so by asking MySQL to pull a row from the table where the primary key equals an ID.

However, this site has a back-end where administrators must be able to pull up a profile based on a name or an e-mail and change the login information for the user if he/she has forgotten their username/password.

Because of this, I must be able to search for a row WITHOUT having the primary key.

How can I search for a row in a table where a column that is not primary contains a string?

**EDIT**

I should have mentioned. I'm storing very large amounts of data. It wasn't economical in code-space or my time to create columns for every single variable that needs to be saved on a thousand-input long form. So, I used one column with deliminators and a bucket sorting algorithm.

Although 'WHERE' is not limited to just the primary key, this means that the name or e-mail of the user will be buried in a string inside a single column. Is there a way to select a row using MySQL equivalent to PHP's 'strpos' function? I.E. If this specific column  in any row contains this string, then that is our row.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeColumn='Some string';`. The `WHERE` clause is not limited to primary key only.

Comment: @Allenph: Apart from a primary key, if at least one other field is defined `unique` you can do a search on it.

Comment: @Allenph: After post edited: BAD design. BAD idea. Don't you think that other field values may also contain your search string !!!????

Comment: @Allenph As for the strpos alternative, see [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) clause. E.g. `... WHERE SomeColumn LIKE '%SomeSubString%'`.

Comment: @RavinderReddy, it seems that way, but you just have to know how it's built to understand why I did it this way. It's not going to be an issue.

Comment: @Allenph: If you have separated each of the values with a *delimiter*, then you can search using `like` with combination of  *delimiter* and search string. **Example** [**Answer** at *How can I perform this string search?*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27941964/767881)

Comment: @RavinderReddy, you've figured out exactly why it won't be a problem. Haha.